# VB.NET excel deleting multiple columns at the same time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel

I am trying to delete more than one column in my excel sheet.

```
    For Each lvi In ListView1.Items
        If lvi.Checked = True Then
            arrayLetters = lvi.SubItems(1).Text & ":" & lvi.SubItems(1).Text & "," & arrayLetters
        End If
    Next

    arrayLetters = arrayLetters.Substring(0, arrayLetters.Length - 1)

    Dim rg As Excel.Range = xlSheet.Columns(arrayLetters)
    rg.Select()
    rg.Delete()
```

The value of **arrayLetters** is **"G:G,F:F"**. For some reason that doesn't seem to work once it gets there to delete them! Only reason i am doing it this way is so that it doesn't update the table and loop to the other one. In other words, if i delete each one individually then the column moves and the letter will not be the same the next go around.

The error is on the **Dim rg As Excel.Range = xlSheet.Columns(arrayLetters)** line and it says:

**Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))**

Any help would be great!

David

**SOLVED**

```
 For Each lvi In ListView1.Items
    If lvi.Checked = False Then
        arrayLetters = lvi.SubItems(2).Text & "," & arrayLetters 'Puts numbers in BACKWORDS
    End If
 Next

 arrayLetters = arrayLetters.Substring(0, arrayLetters.Length - 1)

 Dim theNumbers As String() = arrayLetters.Split(",")
 Dim num As Integer = 0

 xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False

 For Each num In theNumbers
     xlSheet.Columns(num).delete() 'Deletes columns in reverse order (7,5,4...)
 Next
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the lowest numbered column N number of times to reflect how many columns in a row you want to delete. It's better to go off of column numbers rather than letters when dealing with Excel programatically. If you need a code example, let me know and I'll post one.

Edit:

Here is a code example that does what you want:

```
xlSheet.Columns(i).delete
```

Comment: I have it set up as A-Z then AA-AZ, BB-BZ, etc. so it would be nice for me to be able to use that. However, i did try your code and it works for the first pass but error on the second...

Comment: Just keep in mind, that column(1) is column A. Also, as Remou posted, you might want to try getting the Range. Another thing to try is: Columns("F:G").Delete

Comment: I used you're code but still did the arrayLetters but only got the colum numbers instead of letters and **ORDERED THEM BACKWORDS** so that it would not change the order of the columns on each delete.

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
xlSheet.Range(arrayLetters)
```

I reckon, that is Range, not Column.

Answer (score 0):

I think the important part to realize (which I didn't initially) is that you have to use numbers for the columns not the letters.